Definition of mixture of two distributions
What is the formal definition of a mixture of distributions?
Usually one says that we flip a coin, and then choose a distribution out of the two to follow.
Is it formally correct, then, to say that a random variable $X$ has a distribution, which is the mixture (with parameter $p$) of two distributions $D_1$ and $D_2$, denoted $X\sim p D_1+(1-p) D_2$, if there exist an independent Bernoulli random variable $B\sim Ber(p)$ such that $X=B Y_1+(1-B) Y_2$, where $Y_1\sim D_1$ and $Y_2\sim D_2$.
Would this be the most basic definition, or just an equivalent characterization ?

When we specify a mixture distribution, we actually specify a conditional distribution $X \vert B$, where $B \sim \text{Ber}(p)$. That is, we specify $P(X \leq x \vert B = 0)$, and $P(X \leq x \vert B = 1)$ as two different cdfs. As the set of all cdfs is convex, we have that
\begin{align*}
P(X \leq x) &= P(X \leq x \vert B = 0)P(B = 0) + P(X \leq x \vert B = 1)P(B = 1) \\
&= P(X \leq x \vert B = 0)(1-p) + P(X \leq x \vert B = 1)p
\end{align*}
defines a cdf for $X$. Furthermore, if we had had a distribution on $X$ alone, the law of total probability would give us the above expression. Hence, specifying the distributions this way, gives us a direct correspondence between $X|B$ and $B$ with the pair (X, B). Therefore, it is possible to define distributions as mixtures. What you give as a definition is equivalent to this, but is maybe less insightful.

Thank you. I see, so the more fundamental point of view is the distributional one, which I actually reversed engineered to get back to explicit random variables, via the law of total probability. One thing I am confused about, now that you mention it: what do you mean by correspondence between $X|B$, $B$ and $(X,B)$?

Do you perhaps mean that the joint cdf of $(X,B)$ is the product of the conditional cdf of $X|B$ times the cdf of $B$ or you are actually referring to some coupling?
